# Can't run Composer

Tags: windows-10, php, web, composer

I've just installed Composer and then tried to run it, but it fails:

```
prompt>composer
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 
prompt>composer -v
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I checked Env Paths... There is no answer related to this problem in the Internet.

UPD:

Program installed via win installer from getcomposer web site. 
It's placed in its default location.

```
C:\>where composer
C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.1-x64\composer.bat
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat

C:\>php -v PHP 7.1.22 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 00:43:40) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies.
```

Comment: How did you install Composer? Where did you install it? Is PHP on your path? What is the output of `where composer`? // It is better to include command line content as text. On the Windows command line, you can select text with your mouse and then copy it using _Enter_. Don’t forget to format it as code using the _{ }_ button in the editor toolbar!

Comment: Daniel B Via installer. It's placed in its default location. Where: `C:\>where composer
C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.1-x64\composer.bat
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat`. php: `C:\>php -v
PHP 7.1.22 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 00:43:40) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies`.

Comment: Additional information should be included in the question not added as comments.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: had exactly the same problem just now, currently on Windows 11 - Developer Mode worked but I had to re-add the PHP path into the system PATH variable, as the installer just removed it and never re-added it... thanks for this tip, I was struggling with this error for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Okay. IDK how it works, but i just installed composer with "Developer mode" and select a "C:\" path. After this actions it started working. Amazing stuff...